# meaning of the phrase "very well" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [article](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/3-reasons-why-bulletproof-coffee-is-a-bad-idea#section1). Here it is:

> Some is good, even downright healthy, but too much could **very well** be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**very well**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/very%20well) (idiom): 2: reasonably or properly, *I can't **very well** show up at the wedding uninvited.*

In your example it's just an expression synonymous with "reasonably". It's often used with conditionals to indicate plausibility. Other examples:

> Although the weather forecast says it's going to be clear, it **very well** might rain tomorrow, so bring your umbrella.
>
> Our team could **very well** take the title this year.